# When does a PDA halt?

Tags: automata, pushdown-automata

In DFA/NFA the automaton halts when it finishes reading the string.

In a PDA there's the string and the stack. When the string is finished and there are symbols on the stack does it ignore them? Or does it have to pop them?

Or maybe does the behavior depend on whether the PDA is deterministic or not?

---

Here's an example to demonstrate where the ambiguity is.

It's a dumb example and it can be done with a DFA but just for demonstration.

[image: PDA]

This PDA should accept anything but the string `aa`.

It starts by inserting a `$` to mark the bottom of the stack. Then it inserts 2 `a`s. Then when it receives an a it pops one from a stack. It can do that twice.

Now at this point suppose that the input string was indeed `aa`, **and** that the machine reached state `x` and popped the two `a`s. Now the stack has only `$` in it.

- Does it have to go to the next state (`y`) because there's a `$` on top of the stack?
- Or by non-determinism can it be either in `x` or in `y`?

If the latter is true then this is a wrong PDA for this language. It would accept everything.

Comment: There is a whole class of PDA that by definition don't ever pop from the stack at all: nonerasing PDAs.

Comment: Look at the definition; different things are possible.

Answer (score 4):

The setup places $aa\$$ on the stack and puts the machine in state $x$. We then have this sequence of moves on input $aa$:

1. Consume the first $a$ and pop the stack. We're then still in state $x$ with stack contents $a\$$. No other move is possible.
2. Consume the next $a$ and pop the stack. We're then still in state $x$ with stack contents $\$$. No other move is possible.
3. Seeing a $\$$ on the stack, the only possible move is to pop the $\$$ and pass to state $y$.
4. In state $y$ with no further input, there are no possible moves, so the machine halts, in a non-accepting state.

Notice that there's no nondeterminism here: perhaps you were mistaken in your first bullet point: indeed there is a $\$$ **in** the stack at move (1), but it's not on the **top** of the stack.

The deeper question is exactly what model of a PDA is being used here: some people allow multiple accept states and say that the PDA accepts a string if it is in an accept state when the input has been completely consumed, others require that the stack be empty when the input has been consumed; some require a single accept state, some don't. All these models are equivalent, but you need to look closely at the definition you are using.

Comment: note that I meant `on top of`. edited it. My question is in number 3. `Seeing a $ on the stack, the only possible move is to pop the $ and pass to state y`. Is there non-determinism in this step? Meaning; after this step, is the state of the machine `y` only or (`y` or `x`) by non-determinism?

Comment: @MinaMichael At that step there's no nondeterminism: without consuming any input (there's no more anyway), you pass to state $y$. You only have nondeterminism if in a given configuration (state, input character, stack top) there's more than one possible move.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, with $\epsilon$-moves there is some problem with acceptance for PDA even when they are deterministic.

The input of a PDA is accepted when the input is completely read and the chosen acceptance condition is met. This acceptance condition is either reaching a final state or reaching the empty stack. However, immediately after reading the last symbol of the input it might be possible to continue with $\epsilon$-moves on the input.
Thus, we might reach a final state later, or move from a final state to a non-final state. This does not matter only the possibility to enter such a state matters.

To be precise, "halting" is not required, only the possibility of reaching the acceptance condition.  Whatever is possible later does not count. In some 'theoretical' constructions this might be a problem: even for deterministic machines we cannot check the first state entered after reading the input. In fact the computation might accept when at the same time it is possible to run off in an infinite run of $\epsilon$-moves.

In classic definitions it is not possible to make moves on the empty stack, transitions are always required to make one pop. In your case you do allow transitions with empty stack. This *does* change the class of languages accepted by deterministic PDA, since in the classic definition those are 'prefix-free': after accepting one is in the empty stack, and no further symbols can be read.